# Form Automatically Submitting Upon Pressing 'Enter'

Tags: forms

I have a very simple form with a single autocomplete widget.  No submit button.  I would like the form to act in such a way that it submits the form when the user selects a suggestion from the autocomplete, but does not submit otherwise.  The problem is, the form automatically submits, filled in or not, whenever I press enter.  However, if I add a hidden text input box, it resolves the issue, and I can only submit the form by selecting a suggestion from the autocomplete (submission via this mechanism is handled by some jQuery).  Is there a more 'graceful' way of turning off the submit-on-return feature?  Adding a hidden text input that I don't actually need definitely does not seem like the 'proper' way to do this and is probably a browser-dependent fix anyways (I'm using Chrome).

Comment: Can you give a context for more details, it is easy to give the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you actually mean by context?  Do you want the code, what exactly I want this functionality for, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "submit on enter" is a browser specific implementation. So I don't think there is anything we can do from JS to turn it off.

---

You might be able to force the issue by listening to "keypress" event in jQuery, but that seems heavy handed.

---

Another way you could possibly approach this (in theory, never done this) is using HTML5 Data attributes. i.e. on your form, have

```
<form data-ready="false">
</form>
```

Then set that attribute to "true" when you've selected your suggestion item.

In your Form submit handler, check for that attribute before deciding to allow form submission, or use .preventDefault() to stop it from submitting to server.